# Which method should theoretically be best?

Tags: neural-network, ocr

Say I want to recognize my characters using neural network(s). Let's cut it down to 5 letters, the binary form of image to 16x16, input + 2 layers network, unipolar function inside both layers. Momentum backpropagation is used in the process of learning.

Which of the following approaches should give the best results (where x is the number of neurons in the first layer)? By best I mean highest % of correct recognitions. Speed isn't a factor in this question.

1. A single network, 256;x;5 - the highest value neuron wins.
2. 5 networks, 256;x;1 - each network has it's own letter, each output is tested vs a treshold, could happen that 2 or more networks recognize an image as "their own"
3. Same as above, but now the output from each network is normalized (if a,b,c,d,e are outputs, then a = a / (a+b+c+d+e); b = b / (a+b+c+d+e) and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 is the worst option because "2 or more networks recognize an image as "their own"" will definitly happen many times and how you descriminate between them after that? 1 will work reasonable well. 3 is the basic idea behind softmax output function and softmax usually works best for classification tasks especially when combined with cross-entropy error function.

Comment: I should clarify, the 2nd option will use a dynamic treshold based on false acceptance and false rejection errors, to find a value for the treshold so roughly 50:50 f.acceptance/f.rejection error ratio is maintained. That should in theory eliminate the "2 or more networks recognize true" problem.

Comment: @Januszoff yes, optimized thresholds might improve perfomance, but they are unlikely to eliminate the problem completly, since all networks will still decide independently. And that also means that you have 5 more hyperparamenters to fine-tune, so more work, more problems with overfit.